# Will Windows handle any memory not freed as well as threads not closed?

Tags: c, windows, memory

If I had an application that pretty much had a "fail-safe" as in, if I need to terminate the application quickly and not free the malloc'd memory, or close the threads that are running, would Windows handle giving the memory back and terminating the threads?

Comment: You would need to actualy call `abort()`, or similar to actually notify the system to terminate the application. The thread itself dying does not necessarily cause program termination.

Answer (score 9):

[Terminating a process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/terminating-a-process) has the following results:

- Any remaining threads in the process are marked for termination.
- Any resources allocated by the process (including malloc'd memory) are freed.
- All kernel objects are closed.
- The process code is removed from memory.
- The process exit code is set.
- The process object is signaled.